# React keeps children from previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have problem rendering page based on array of templates stored in redux. I'm unable to provide the actual code as it is too complex to reproduce in sandbox, but I will try with simplified structure.

I have pinterest-style grid based on `flex-grow` and js calculations for each item based on its dimensions so I need to have all of this inside one container.

I have 3 groups of items in same div:

`blank_item` + `templates.map` + `tailItems.map`

```
<div className="grid">
    {shouldRenderBlankItem && <BlankItem />}
    {templates.map((template) => (
        <Template
            key={template.uuid}
            template={template}
        />
    ))}
    {shouldRenderTail &&
        tailItems.map(item, i) => (
            <TailItem
                key={i}
                item={item}
            />
        ))}
</div>
```

The problem is - sometimes after render I have EXTRA  children left from previous render and React puts them in front of other elements within `div.grid` so the result I have will look like:

`3-4 of EXTRA <Template/>` + `blank_item` + `templates.map` + `tailItems.map`

As a key for Template I use `template.uuid` that is coming from backend and I know they're unique and react also doesn't show any warnings for duplicated keys - so I know I'm not getting any duplicated items from API what I thought might be an issue.

Redux is fine - I see correct number of `templates` in it e.g. 50, `grid` and react dev tools  shows same 50 templates coming as a prop when I inspect parent component, but the actual DOM has e.g. 53  elements in the same moment.

How can I debug issue like this? I suppose something is wrong during reconciliation but I don't know where exactly to start debugging this.

I have React/ReactDOM 16.13.1

Comment: A common mistake I have made before that resulted in such issue was to mutate some state somewhere, noy saying this is the case just pointing out.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer thanks mate, the only suspicious part in reducer I see is `const items = shouldAppendItems ? [...state.items, ...newItemsFromApi] : newItemsFromApi; return {...state, items}` but that feels like a correct way to me (the case where I combine 2 arrays together is used to load more items to the same page and it works fine, the case where I have problem is when I get newItemsFromApi and I see redux has only those items in the store)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so in my case **the problem was broken backend api which might return same template twice** - so uuid's that I use for keys were unique for each template but they are not really unique in terms of the page and DOM elements.

I faced this only in production build that is why I didn't have `duplicated key` warning (on dev build I have another DB with much less templates so I was unable to reproduce this).

So anyone facing similar issue: go check your keys are really unique within page, because what happens after new templates load comes:

1. React wants to remove old item
2. It searches corresponding DOM element for each key and finds item with `key="XXX"` and removes it from DOM
3. Their duplicated items stays in DOM as corresponding key was processed and React doesn't care about this particular key anymore
4. We load new templates and they get appended to the parent container
5. Voila! We have old items before newly loaded

What I did here - my key now is:

```
templates.map((template, i) => <Template key={template.uuid + i} />
```

So in this case I am safe even if backend returns duplicated items.
Of course we will fix backend as well. Thanks for reading and helping!

Just quick example how to search for items with same `id` in `data`:

```
var duplicates = new Set();
data.map(t => t.id).forEach((id, i, arr) => {if(arr.filter(item => item == id).length > 1){
duplicates.add(id);
}});
console.log("DUPLICATED IDs:", duplicates)
```